# Google Extension issue xhr request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, request

Failed to show response data but status still (200 OK)

Here is images 
Looks like request still normal

[image]

But problem with response data :/

[image: but still problem with data]

Comment: this problem happens when i changed base URL http to https

Comment: That may be a bug in devtools. What happens in your own code? Does it receive the response if you do console.log for example? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: yes i received when i trying to console.log from code O_O

Comment: No errors in console